# Android: drawing bitmaps with sub-pixel coordinates

Tags: android, bitmap

I've just noticed that despite `Canvas.drawBitmap()` taking float coordinates (some variants, at least), it performs no sub-pixel anti-aliasing when blitting. That is, the bitmap is always drawn at exact integer coordinates (in my code I use no scaling, canvas matrix is identity, done `paint.setFilterBitmap(true)`).

Can someone confirm this observation? If this is not supported, are there any known plans to include the anti-aliasing blitting feature?

Comment: I can confirm this behaviour on 2.X and 4.X devices. Mainly on tablets (big screens), this is very well visible.

Comment: Confirmed. I had 1x1 image scaled to look like 0.5x200 line and it is not visible. I have tried 
   paint.setAntiAlias(true);
   paint.setFilterBitmap(true); with no result

Answer (score 2):

According to Romain Guy in a [similar Google group question](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/android-platform/X5jsiiQbc_Q):

> bitmaps (and other primitives) are always drawn pixel-aligned if the current transform is only a translation. Any other transform will perform sub-pixel positioning.

So an easy solution is

```
Canvas.scale(1.00001f, 1.00001f);
```